"Leibniz's rule" for $t\in\mathbb{R}^n$
I am looking for a reference giving a measure-theoretic proof of a claim from the German Wikipedia. I have searched the references given on that site, as well as the English speaking Wikipedia and all multivariate calculus and measure theory books I could think of, yet I did not find a proof.
The statement is this:
Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ open, $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ measure space, $(E, \Vert \cdot \Vert)$ Banach space. For $f \colon U \times \Omega \to E$ s.t.

$f(u, \cdot) \in \mathcal{L}_1(\Omega, \mu, E)$ for all $u \in U$,
$f(\cdot, \omega) \in C^1(U, E)$ for $\mu$-almost all $\omega \in \Omega$,
There exists $g \in \mathcal{L}_1(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mu; \mathbb{R}_+)$ with $\Vert \partial_u f(u, \omega) \Vert \leqslant g(\omega)$ for $(u, \omega) \in U \times \Omega$.

Then
$$
F \colon U \to E, \ u \mapsto \int_\Omega f(u, \omega) \mu(\mathrm{d}\omega)
$$
continuously differentiable with
$$
\partial_j F(u) = \int_\Omega \frac{\partial}{\partial u^j} f(u, \omega) \mu(\mathrm{d}\omega), \quad u \in U, \quad 1 \leqslant j \leqslant d.
$$
I am aware of the measure theoretic version of Leibniz's rule. But there it is assumed that $t\in\mathbb{R}$. I care about the $t\in\mathbb{R}^n,n>1$ case. There has to exist at least one proper reference in the world which actually includes a proof of this.
P.S.: Is the continuous differentiability even relevant? Is the analogous statement for differentiability (without continuity) also true?

What is $t$? There's no use of that symbol in any of your formulas.

Prove it by using dominated convergence and the mean value inequality or fundamental theorem of calculus to bound by $g$.

Partial derivatives are derivatives of single-variable functions obtained by fixing all other points, so the proof is easily reduced to the case $n=1$. If you want a reference, look at Amann Escher, Vol III, Theorem 3.18. Anyway even this result an be generalized; you can consider the case of $U$ being open in a Banach space; you simply need to use a corresponding version of the mean-value inequality (for which continuity of the derivative is not needed of course).
